# Azure Function is in Read Only mode

Tags: function, azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure Function in Visual Studio 2017 15.4.3. I am attempting to deploy/publish to Azure. Everything SEEMS to work okay, but the function in portal shows up as read-only. I have attempted to change the Mode to readwrite, but it does not hold. It reverts upon refresh. I have tried creating the Function App in both the portal AND in Visual Studio. Both result in a Read Only Function App which is useless. The API returns a 404. The App Service url does show that the App Service is up and running. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!!

[image: Read Only Mode]

Comment: I have noticed this behavior when we deploy the function through visual studio as a new function app. When a function app is created through portal , and if we use the same in visual studio I was able to change the read only mode.

Comment: Baskar - Thanks for the reply. Are you saying you were able to get it to work when creating it from the Portal? The Read Only setting I see is in the App settings, NOT the function settings. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I remember while playing around with functions. But not sure if something has changed.

Comment: That's expected behavior. It means you can't modify this function app content from the portal. What's your problem with that?

Comment: Mikhail - Oh, I thought it meant it could not be executed. I thought that was a part of my problem. The problem is I am getting a 404 and thought it had to do with that.

Comment: @Mikhail technically there is nothing to change if a function is developed and deployed using Visual Studio. In that case we need to disable the option to edit the read only mode option in portal for precompiled functions. Even though you try to change it as false, it gets overwritten again. This leads to confusion.

Comment: @Todd I don't think it related. Provide more details about your binding and request

Comment: @Todd are you able to test the function from portal after deployment?

Comment: Mikhail - I am creating a default function, HelloWorld and publish it without making any changes. It is HTTP Trigger, anonymous. I publish it and only can ever get a 404.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot the "/api/" in the url. Sorry guys. Thanks for clarifying the read-only issue @Mikhail. And thanks Baskar for your feedback! You guys really helped me to figure out the issue was ME!!

Comment: @Mikhail, the sandbox really helped. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was testing the wrong URL. However, I did learn that the Azure Function is Read Only because of the manner it was published and had nothing to do with my issue. Thanks to @Mikhail for that!

Comment: I have tried. I have to wait 48 hours...21 hours remaining. Thanks.

Comment: This is be design. The only way you can edit azure function from the portal is if you created it from there and continued editing it from portal only. Once you deploy it using any other mode it is set to read only to be consistent

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect `function.json` issue generated by VS2017. There are multiple error coming while publishing from VS2017.

fix: remove below two lines

```
"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0",

"configurationSource": "attributes",
```

One more fix if you are working with Http trigger  then add one line after binding configration:

```
"direction": "in"
```

Hope this will help.

More details at [Azure-Function](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/478) and [Azure-Function issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/480)